# Splitting in python

Tags: python, string, split

The string is in the below format.

```
A1:::x1:::B1.A2:::x2::x3::x4:::B2.A3:::x5::x6::x7:::B3.
```

The output after splitting should be

```
['x1:::B1', 'x2::x3::x4:::B2', 'x5::x6::x7:::B3']
```

Note:

- A,x is separated by `:::`
- x1,x2....xn are separated by `::`
- x,B is separated by `:::`
- B,A is separared by `.`

Comment: And what did you try so far mate? What is your problem with that? You will find that people here (like me) want you to show some effort, not just ask to get your homework done.

Comment: @Puciek: That wasn’t my intention. But, I appreciate your suggestion in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you want to split first on `.` (removing empty entries) then split once on `:::` keeping only the second element.  In code, that looks like this:

```
s = 'A1:::x1:::B1.A2:::x2::x3::x4:::B2.A3:::x5::x6::x7:::B3.'
slist = (substr for substr in s.split('.') if substr)
result = [x.split(":::",1)[1] for x in slist]
```

As noted in the comments, we can state this more succinctly:

```
result = [x.split(":::",1)[1] for x in s.split('.') if x]
```

Comment: +1 but I would do `[x.split(":::",1)[1] for x in s.split('.') if x]`

Comment: @jamylak -- Yes, I suppose that would do it, wouldn't it :).  Thanks.  I think I'll leave the first version as it follows the flow of logic in the text a little more naturally, but I'll include your update as well.  The other thing that I like about the first version is that it makes it a little easier to add validation to make sure that we're getting elements which can be split by `:::` into 2 pieces.